# Why can't show dialog in laravel 5.4?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

html:

```
   <input id="btnShowAdd" name="btnShowAdd" type="button" value="Add" onclick="showformadd()">
   <div class="modal-content" id="myModal">
              hello
   </div>
```

Script show a modal dialog:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
            function showformadd() {
                $("#myModal").modal('show');
            }

 </script>
```

Result: not exist error, but can't show dialog. Why? 
How can show dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without CSS it will not work!

Use this instead your scripts and add boostrap.min.css too:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to follow the modal markup. In your html change the markup to this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
         <div class="modal-content">
             <div class="modal-body">
                 Hello
             </div>
         </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It still can't show, it only bold border: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fsjowghwd9hzleg/2017-11-10%2010-44-19.png?dl=0

Comment: Did you add the bootstrap css files? @DT

Comment: popper.min.js and bootstrap.min.css